# How many CPU cores should be in my MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, processor, system-information

It looks like something's seriously wrong...

My Air should have 4 cores. However, I saw that the number of cores has sunk to 2 when I was going to make a new virtual machine...

I checked out what *System Information* says and the result doesn't match with the one I get by running *htop* in *Terminal*. Please, check out these screenshots:

`htop`:
[image]

System Information:

[image]

I don't understand... Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: What does "when I was going to make a new virtual machine" look like? Using docker v 1.10, or xhyve 0.2.0 or some other version/make of virtualization engine?

Answer (score 4):

Your MacBook Air has 2 independent processor cores.

When Hyper Threading is used, each core can act as two. In this case you will see four computational cores.

The [EveryMac page for your MacBook Air](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-2.0-11-mid-2012-specs.html) explains why you are seeing four in some situations and two in the System Information application:

> This model is powered by a 22 nm, 64-bit Intel Mobile Core i7 "Ivy Bridge" (I7-3667U) processor which includes **two independent processor "cores" on a single silicon chip**. Each core has a dedicated 256k level 2 cache, shares 4 MB of level 3 cache, and has an integrated memory controller (dual channel).
>
> This system also supports "Turbo Boost 2.0" -- which "automatically increases the speed of the active cores" to improve performance when needed (up to 3.2 GHz for this model) -- and "Hyper Threading" -- **which allows the system to recognize four total "cores"** or "threads" (two real and two virtual).

Answer (score 0):

Your MacBook Air has only two cores (4 threads). That is what htop is showing.